# Propagate user access right from an authentication web page to other html only web pages on the server?

Tags: node.js, apache, authentication, access-control, federation

I want to create a web page, that will serve to authenticate users based on credentials I give them (user1, pswd1 etc).
Only after a user authenticated, he should have access to a few other web sites,
on different folders of the web server, but which have no server side code
(otherwise it would be simple.)
The user should be allowed access to the other sites, e.g. based on his IP,
for 24 hours or another period, or while he has the authentication site open on his browser.
The purpose if that the user will not have to enter credentials on each site,
and will enter his credentials only once, or once a day.

Restrictions:

  I don't want to modify the target web site javascript code at all, e.g. to query a web service.

  The user should be granted access using any browser, 
  so I assume I cannot use cookies.

If I would develop such a mechanism on Apache,I could, for example, have the authentication site PHP code add a line "Allow from ip" to the htaccess file of each target web folder, whenever a user authenticated successfully.

The issue is that I don't want to develop it as I am sure a solution already exists, and also I need a similar mechanism for both Apache and node.js (although i can live with two different solutions)

Answer (score 0):

What information does the user have to identify themselves? How do you guarantee the user is who they say they are?

The whole point of authentication is to establish the user is who they say they are and that may create a session so that users need not reauthenticate.

If you want the user to authenticate in a single location and then reuse that "session" or set of credentials elsewhere, what you are looking for is single-sign-on / identity federation.

For instance, take airbnb.com. I do not need to authenticate there. All I have to do is authenticate with a third-party e.g. Google or Facebook. As a matter of fact, SO works in the same way.

One of the standards behind this technique is called Open ID Connect. Look into that. If you are willing to dish out money, you can look into commercial solutions e.g. Ping Identity. There is an open source implementation provided by Mitre / the MIT. It's [available here](https://github.com/mitreid-connect/).

Answer (score 0):

In fact it occurs to me I can use simple routing.
In the top level folder have php code that does the authentication.
If the user is authenticated, route/redirect to the requested target site,
based on the requested url.
 
The url should be for example http://mysite/site1, where the authentication code is in the folder mysite, and site1 is not directly accessible.
Perhaps I can use something like [php-express](https://www.npmjs.com/package/php-express) to reuse the same php code on node.js.